Do we need SP800 tag
sp800 tag has only 3 questions with no watcher. Do we really need this tag? There is already nist with 117 questions and 4 watchers.

Gap was 5 already, merged it into NIST and removed SP800

No, we don't need. nist enough for all of the NIST documents.
Fill in a reason, Community!

Yes, we need this tag.
Fill in a reason, Community!
